# Cannot set full resolution using USB-C docking station

Tags: multiple-monitors, resolution, external-display, usb-c, docking-station

I am using USB-C docking station (Dell WD-19) with HP notebook. I've connect 2 monitors to that station - 1st over DisplayPort and 2nd over HDMI. Basically everything works fine, but in the 4K monitor (HDMI) I cannot set the resolution higher than 1920x1080, while on the 1st monitor, I can set max resolution (3440x1440).

[Settings screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qKnzA.png)

Do you have any idea what can be wrong? Is there some limitation over the USB-C? I've tried to update the GPU drivers but it didn't help.

Comment: Make sure the HDMI port supports at least HDMI 1.4 better 2.0; same for the used cable. Older HDMI versions are too slow to provide 4K resolutions (too much data to transfer per second). Also read the manual if two 4K monitors are supported by the hub at all. The USB-C bandwidth may limit this.

Comment: I had a similiar problem with my corporate laptop attached to two QHD (2560x1440) monitors. IT told me that they needed to enable some "high resolution over USB-C" setting (can't recall the actual term, maybe different) in the laptop's BIOS. They did and now it works seamlessly. Maybe that's a pointer?